# How does torch.no_grad work that makes inner tensors without grad?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, contextmanager

For example:

```py
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
with torch.no_grad():
  b = torch.tensor([1.])
  y = x * 2 + b
```

How do `y` and `b` know they should be initialized with `requires_grad=False`?

AFAIK, from [the source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd/grad_mode.html#no_grad) for `torch.no_grad()`, it will finally call `torch._C._set_grad_enabled(False)`. I am stuck here because I do not know what happened with this call. Is it setting a global variable that tensors can access when initializing and thus tensors know it does not require gradient for now?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because a tensor that is calculated from other tensors never requires grad by default no matter the context (grad or no grad). `torch._C._set_grad_enabled(False)` simply deactivate all methods `save_for_backward` that save required tensors for computing backprop later and do not create nodes and edges used for C++ backprop graph.